# Speeding up page transitions the right way

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I would like some tips.
I am experimenting the 300ms delay on 
phonegap + JQM + HTML5BoilerPlate + IOS6.
Although I installed and called new FastClick(), I still end up with the same delay!
Is there a way to test that FastClick is actually performing at its best ?
Is there another normal ~300ms delay I am focusing and misleaded on ?
What is the expected time transition between a `<a>` click and its page load event done ?
Note: the html file contains all pages.

```
<body ... onload='init()' ...>
function init(){ new FastClick(document.body); }

...
$.mobile.bind('vclick', ... 
   $.mobile.changePage('#...', {transition: "none"});
```

Added later in discussion:
[image: ![Timeline on observed events and calls]

Comment: Expected time to transition : ~300 Ms is default time the browser waits before firing the event, as you know it is because it waits for a double tap/click. check this once :https://forum.jquery.com/topic/google-s-fastbutton

They are basically playing around with touch events, but we need a fallback for non-touch devices with onClick. And to my knowledge, console.log() 'ing the time(in ms) is the only near-perfect way to measure this logic performing. Hope it helped.

Comment: @Futur, does your expected 300MS is corresponding to the (a ms; standing for 'amount of milliseconds in variable a in the above drawing)?  Yet I was not able to use console.log() on ios and see them on xcode.  Meanwhile I use a div to view the logs directly the device.

Comment: ...Meanwhile I use a div to view the logs directly saved on the device.

Comment: As said above, 300 ms(milli seconds) to fire the click event and i liked the device logs idea of yours,  i would like to know how you fetched the device logs directly.. if you can post or provide a link will be cool :)

Comment: The logging feature will be provided in a github repo soon, since it is general to our developpers, it's nothing fancy, but it does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing transitions if you want to speed it up

```
     $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
     $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
     $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
     }
```

you can also create custom transition
 http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

Here you can change the .in, .out rule to set custom times

```
     .in, .out {
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 200ms;
     }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Aravind, I already used the transition set to none, although, your technique is more general, thanks.  I do not know about the in and out css settings.  I will investigate.